# Access webservice via ssl - ServerCertificateValidationCallback not called

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, .net-4.0

I need to access a Webservice  via https that has some problems with its certificate. In chrome it shows that the identity of the website is confirmed, but that there is no public entry.

When issuing an httprequest to that url i get an error System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.SecureChannelFailure

> "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I tried do disable certificate validation by using

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
    if (error == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'",
        cert.Subject,
        error.ToString());

    return false;
}
```

But the callback is not even hit. If I request a different (valid) URL, the callback is hit.

Is there any way I can debug further into the issue?

Here is the complete sample code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string url = "https://domainwithsslissues.";
        string method = "get";

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

        HttpWebRequest ws = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        ws.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        ws.Method = method;

        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ws.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, true))
                {
                    string response = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                    responseStreamReader.Close();
                }

                responseStream.Close();
            }
            webResponse.Close();
        }
    }

    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        if (error == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'",
            cert.Subject,
            error.ToString());

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the Webservice required TSL 1.1. or 1.2 which is not supported in .NET 4